# Rails + Devise: How to invoke login and signup in different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This is the code for my ajax call

```
var data = {user: {password: password, email: email}};
$.post('auto_login',data,function(res){
  if(res.success){
    // successfully logged in
  }
  else{
    // failed log in
  }
});
```

This is the code in my controller

```
def auto_login
  @user = parmas[:user]

  # how do i invoke login here...
  # res = Sessions.new(@user)
  # x = true if res.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json{ render :json => { :success => x } }
  end
end
```

I am doing this because I have a button which if a unregistered user clicks it will pop-up a modal window which ask for login info or register to the site. After the user fills up the required information, and if the system recognize that the data are valid, it will automatically redirect the user to a particular url.

Any help will do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Devise allows you to put the log in form anywhere. You can put it in a partial or use javascript to show/hide. Just follow these instructions:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app